# How to add padding around an email using Zurb Ink

Tags: html, css, email, html-table, zurb-ink

I am using http://zurb.com/ink/ to build my email template, but I need to have a 10px border around the edge of the email.

When I try to add padding to the email using a class called .box-edge (this is a custom class) it adds the padding but when the screen is resized the images dont resize correctly.

**Here's a fiddle to show what I mean:**
http://jsfiddle.net/daimz/xspWL/2/

And here is the code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<table class="body">
  <tr>
    <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
      <center>

      <!-- Header -->
      <table class="row header">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="center" align="center">
              <center>
                <table class="container">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="wrapper last">
                        <!-- Twelve Columns -->
                        <table class="twelve columns box-edge">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <!-- Logo -->
                              <td class="six sub-columns" style="vertical-align: middle">
                                <img src="images/capalaba-logo.png" alt="Capalaba Central" />
                              </td>
                              <!-- End Logo -->
                              <!-- View More -->
                              <td class="six sub-columns last" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle;">
                                <a href="#" class="btn green view-all" style="vertical-align: middle">
                                  <span class="btn-copy">View All</span>
                                  <img class="external-link" style="padding-left:5px;" src="images/external-link.png" width="15" height="13" alt="Visit Site">
                                </a>
                              </td>
                              <!-- End View More -->
                              <td class="expander"><!-- Ensures full-width on mobile --></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- End twelve Columns -->
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- End Header -->
      <br>

      <!-- Content -->
      <table class="container">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>

              <!-- Hero Image -->
              <table class="row box-edge">
                <tr>
                  <td class="wrapper last">
                    <table class="twelve columns">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="center">
                          <center>
                            <img class="center" src="http://lorempixel.com/580/300/" alt="Place Holder" />
                          </center>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <!-- End Hero -->

              <!-- Compilers -->
              <!-- 3 blocks -->
              <table class="row box-edge">
                <tr>
                  <td class="wrapper">
                    <table class="four columns">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="center">
                          <center>
                            <img class="center" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" alt="" />
                          </center>
                        </td>
                        <td class="expander"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                  <td class="wrapper">
                    <table class="four columns">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="center">
                          <center>
                            <img class="center" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" alt="" />
                          </center>
                        </td>
                        <td class="expander"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                  <td class="wrapper last">
                    <table class="four columns">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="center">
                          <center>
                            <img class="center" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" alt="" />
                          </center>
                        </td>
                        <td class="expander"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <!-- End 3 blocks -->
              <!-- End Compilers -->

            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>



      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
/**********************************************
* Ink v1.0.4 - Copyright 2013 ZURB Inc        *
**********************************************/

/* Client-specific Styles & Reset */

#outlook a { 
  padding:0; 
} 

body{ 
  width:100% !important; 
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; 
  -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
}

.ExternalClass { 
  width:100%;
} 

.ExternalClass, 
.ExternalClass p, 
.ExternalClass span, 
.ExternalClass font, 
.ExternalClass td, 
.ExternalClass div { 
  line-height: 100%; 
} 

#backgroundTable { 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  width:100% !important; 
  line-height: 100% !important; 
}

img { 
  outline:none; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%; 
  float: left; 
  clear: both; 
  display: block;
}

center {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 580px;
}

a img { 
  border: none;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td { 
  word-break: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse !important; 
}

table, tr, td {
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}

hr {
  color: #d9d9d9; 
  background-color: #d9d9d9; 
  height: 1px; 
  border: none;
}

/* Responsive Grid */

table.body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

table.container {
  width: 580px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: inherit;
}

table.row { 
  padding: 0px; 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

table.container table.row {
  display: block;
}

td.wrapper {
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

table.columns,
table.column {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table.columns td,
table.column td {
  padding: 0px 0px 10px; 
}

table.columns td.sub-columns,
table.column td.sub-columns,
table.columns td.sub-column,
table.column td.sub-column {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

td.sub-column, td.sub-columns {
  min-width: 0px;
}

table.row td.last,
table.container td.last {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

table.one { width: 30px; }
table.two { width: 80px; }
table.three { width: 130px; }
table.four { width: 180px; }
table.five { width: 230px; }
table.six { width: 280px; }
table.seven { width: 330px; }
table.eight { width: 380px; }
table.nine { width: 430px; }
table.ten { width: 480px; }
table.eleven { width: 530px; }
table.twelve { width: 580px; }

table.one center { min-width: 30px; }
table.two center { min-width: 80px; }
table.three center { min-width: 130px; }
table.four center { min-width: 180px; }
table.five center { min-width: 230px; }
table.six center { min-width: 280px; }
table.seven center { min-width: 330px; }
table.eight center { min-width: 380px; }
table.nine center { min-width: 430px; }
table.ten center { min-width: 480px; }
table.eleven center { min-width: 530px; }
table.twelve center { min-width: 580px; }

.body .columns td.one,
.body .column td.one, { width: 8.333333% !important; }
.body .columns td.two,
.body .column td.two { width: 16.666666% !important; }
.body .columns td.three,
.body .column td.three { width: 25% !important; }
.body .columns td.four,
.body .column td.four { width: 33.333333% !important; }
.body .columns td.five,
.body .column td.five { width: 41.666666% !important; }
.body .columns td.six,
.body .column td.six { width: 50% !important; }
.body .columns td.seven,
.body .column td.seven { width: 58.333333% !important; }
.body .columns td.eight,
.body .column td.eight { width: 66.666666% !important; }
.body .columns td.nine,
.body .column td.nine { width: 75% !important; }
.body .columns td.ten,
.body .column td.ten { width: 83.333333% !important; }
.body .columns td.eleven,
.body .column td.eleven { width: 91.666666% !important; }
.body .columns td.twelve,
.body .column td.twelve { width: 100% !important; }

td.offset-by-one { padding-left: 50px; }
td.offset-by-two { padding-left: 100px; }
td.offset-by-three { padding-left: 150px; }
td.offset-by-four { padding-left: 200px; }
td.offset-by-five { padding-left: 250px; }
td.offset-by-six { padding-left: 300px; }
td.offset-by-seven { padding-left: 350px; }
td.offset-by-eight { padding-left: 400px; }
td.offset-by-nine { padding-left: 450px; }
td.offset-by-ten { padding-left: 500px; }
td.offset-by-eleven { padding-left: 550px; }

td.sub-offset-by-one { padding-left: 5.172413% !important; }
td.sub-offset-by-two { padding-left: 13.793102% !important; }
td.sub-offset-by-three { padding-left: 22.413791% !important; }
td.sub-offset-by-four { padding-left: 31.034480% !important; }
td.sub-offset-by-five { padding-left: 39.655169% !important; }
td.sub-offset-by-six { padding-left: 48.275858% !important; }
td.sub-offset-by-seven { padding-left: 56.896547% !important; }
td.sub-offset-by-eight { padding-left: 65.517236% !important; }
td.sub-offset-by-nine { padding-left: 74.137925% !important; }
td.sub-offset-by-ten { padding-left: 82.758614% !important; }
td.sub-offset-by-eleven { padding-left: 91.379303% !important; }

td.expander {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

table.columns .text-pad,
table.column .text-pad {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

table.columns .left-text-pad,
table.columns .text-pad-left,
table.column .left-text-pad,
table.column .text-pad-left {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

table.columns .right-text-pad,
table.columns .text-pad-right,
table.column .right-text-pad,
table.column .text-pad-right {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

/* Block Grid */

.block-grid {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 580px;
}

.block-grid td {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px;
}

.two-up td {
  width:270px;
}

.three-up td {
  width:173px;
}

.four-up td {
  width:125px;
}

.five-up td {
  width:96px;
}

.six-up td {
  width:76px;
}

.seven-up td {
  width:62px;
}

.eight-up td {
  width:52px;
}

/* Alignment & Visibility Classes */

table.center, td.center {
  text-align: center;
}

h1.center,
h2.center,
h3.center,
h4.center,
h5.center,
h6.center {
  text-align: center;
}

span.center {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

img.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}

.show-for-small,
.hide-for-desktop {
  display: none;
}

/* Typography */

body, table.body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p { 
  color: #222222;
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: normal; 
  padding:0; 
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left; 
  line-height: 1.3;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  word-break: normal;
}

h1 {font-size: 40px;}
h2 {font-size: 36px;}
h3 {font-size: 32px;}
h4 {font-size: 28px;}
h5 {font-size: 24px;}
h6 {font-size: 20px;}
body, table.body, p {font-size: 14px;line-height:19px;}

p { 
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

small {
  font-size: 10px;
}

a {
  color: #2ba6cb; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover { 
  color: #2795b6 !important;
}

a:active { 
  color: #2795b6 !important;
}

a:visited { 
  color: #2ba6cb !important;
}

h1 a, 
h2 a, 
h3 a, 
h4 a, 
h5 a, 
h6 a {
  color: #2ba6cb;
}

h1 a:active, 
h2 a:active,  
h3 a:active, 
h4 a:active, 
h5 a:active, 
h6 a:active { 
  color: #2ba6cb !important; 
} 

h1 a:visited, 
h2 a:visited,  
h3 a:visited, 
h4 a:visited, 
h5 a:visited, 
h6 a:visited { 
  color: #2ba6cb !important; 
} 

/* Panels */

td.panel {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  padding: 10px !important;
}

/* Buttons */

table.button,
table.tiny-button,
table.small-button,
table.medium-button,
table.large-button {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table.button td,
table.tiny-button td,
table.small-button td,
table.medium-button td,
table.large-button td {
  display: block;
  width: auto !important;
  text-align: center;
  background: #2ba6cb;
  border: 1px solid #2284a1;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

table.tiny-button td {
  padding: 5px 0 4px;
}

table.small-button td {
  padding: 8px 0 7px;
}

table.medium-button td {
  padding: 12px 0 10px;
}

table.large-button td {
  padding: 21px 0 18px;
}

table.button td a,
table.tiny-button td a,
table.small-button td a,
table.medium-button td a,
table.large-button td a {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

table.tiny-button td a {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table.small-button td a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

table.medium-button td a {
  font-size: 20px;
}

table.large-button td a {
  font-size: 24px;
}

table.button:hover td,
table.button:visited td,
table.button:active td {
  background: #2795b6 !important;
}

table.button:hover td a,
table.button:visited td a,
table.button:active td a {
  color: #fff !important;
}

table.button:hover td,
table.tiny-button:hover td,
table.small-button:hover td,
table.medium-button:hover td,
table.large-button:hover td {
  background: #2795b6 !important;
}

table.button:hover td a,
table.button:active td a,
table.button td a:visited,
table.tiny-button:hover td a,
table.tiny-button:active td a,
table.tiny-button td a:visited,
table.small-button:hover td a,
table.small-button:active td a,
table.small-button td a:visited,
table.medium-button:hover td a,
table.medium-button:active td a,
table.medium-button td a:visited,
table.large-button:hover td a,
table.large-button:active td a,
table.large-button td a:visited {
  color: #ffffff !important; 
}

table.secondary td {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  border-color: #d0d0d0;
  color: #555;
}

table.secondary td a {
  color: #555;
}

table.secondary:hover td {
  background: #d0d0d0 !important;
  color: #555;
}

table.secondary:hover td a,
table.secondary td a:visited,
table.secondary:active td a {
  color: #555 !important;
}

table.success td {
  background: #5da423;
  border-color: #457a1a;
}

table.success:hover td {
  background: #457a1a !important;
}

  table.alert td {
    background: #c60f13;
    border-color: #970b0e;
  }

  table.alert:hover td {
    background: #970b0e !important;
  }

  table.radius td {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  table.round td {
    -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
    -moz-border-radius: 500px;
    border-radius: 500px;
  }

  /* Outlook First */

  body.outlook p {
    display: inline !important;
  }

  /*  Media Queries */

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  table[class="body"] img {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] center {
    min-width: 0 !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .container {
    width: 95% !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .row {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .wrapper {
    display: block !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .columns,
  table[class="body"] .column {
    table-layout: fixed !important;
    float: none !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    display: block !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .wrapper.first .columns,
  table[class="body"] .wrapper.first .column {
    display: table !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] table.columns td,
  table[class="body"] table.column td {
    width: 100% !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-one,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-two,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-three,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-four,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-five,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-six,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-seven,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-eight,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-nine,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-ten,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-eleven {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .expander {
    width: 9999px !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .right-text-pad,
  table[class="body"] .text-pad-right {
    padding-left: 10px !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .left-text-pad,
  table[class="body"] .text-pad-left {
    padding-right: 10px !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .hide-for-small,
  table[class="body"] .show-for-desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .show-for-small,
  table[class="body"] .hide-for-desktop {
    display: inherit !important;
  }



  /* 
  // Your custom styles go here 
  */
  .green{
    background: #b1ba1d;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  body {
    background: #ebebeb;
  }
  .container{
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  .box-edge{
    margin:10px !important;
  }
  .header .container{
    border-bottom: 4px solid #b1ba1d;
  }
  .btn{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;

    vertical-align: middle;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  .btn-copy, .btn img{
    padding: 2px 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .btn img{
    padding-left: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
  }
  .green:hover{
    background: #949b1b;
  }
  .green img{
    border-left:1px dotted #dee26c;
  }
  .green:hover span{
    color: #feffea;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

From [Ink docs](http://zurb.com/ink/docs.php):

> A fairly common use case for the container is to give your text a white background to separate it from a colored email body. To assist with this design pattern, we've included three helper classes with Ink: `.text-pad`, .`left-text-pad` and `.right-text-pad`.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <table class="body">
        <tr>
            <td class="center" align="center">
                <center>
                    <table class="row">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="wrapper last">
                                <table class="twelve columns">
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- Following td gives the margin:  -->
                                        <td class="text-pad">
                                            <!-- Content with margin of 10px side -->
                                            <table class="row" style="background-color: #e6e6e6;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="wrapper">
                                                        <table class="six columns ">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>Left content</td>
                                                                <td class="expander"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="wrapper last">
                                                        <table class="six columns">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>Right content</td>
                                                                <td class="expander"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="expander"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation of your changes to help improve your answer.